# Creating tool from script using ArcPy gives error 000714

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-script-tool, error-000714

The script is fully functional, but I need to convert it into a tool which will allow the user to customize work environment, expression, name of shapefile, name title text, update date text automatically, and select a output file.

The error message is:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'GDB_ReleaseInfo'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

[image]

[image]

I am new to ArcPy.

```
   # Import arcpy module
... import arcpy
... 
... #Set Work Environment Default File
... myWS = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
... if myWS == '#' or not myWS:
...     myWS = r"C:/Tmp/GIS_Tmp" # Default value if none passed to script
... 
... #arcpy.env.workspace = myWS
... #arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Tmp\GIS_Tmp"
... 
... # Script arguments
... Parcels = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
... 
... Selection_type = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
... if Selection_type == '#' or not Selection_type:
...     Selection_type = "NEW_SELECTION" # provide a default value if unspecified
... 
... Distance__Buff1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
... if Distance__Buff1 == '#' or not Distance__Buff1:
...     Distance__Buff1 = "300 Feet" # provide a default value if unspecified
... 
... Distance__Buff2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
... if Distance__Buff2 == '#' or not Distance__Buff2:
...     Distance__Buff2 = "500 Feet" # provide a default value if unspecified
... 
... Expression = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
... if Expression == '#' or not Expression:
...     Expression = "\"AIN\" = ''" # provide a default value if unspecified
... 
... v300ft_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
... 
... v500ft_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
... 
... 
... # Local variables:
... #Parcel_Address = Parcels
... 
... #If layer already exist overwrite
... arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
... 
... #Create Parcels layer
... arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/Tmp/GIS_Tmp/Parcels.shp","Parcels.lyr")
...                                   
... 
... # Process: Select Layer By Attribute
... arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Parcels.lyr", Selection_type, Expression)
... 
... # identify the current map document
... 
... mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
...     
... # identify the data frame
... df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
...     
... # use the zoom to selected features method of the data frame to update the extent
... df.zoomToSelectedFeatures ()
... 
... #Set Scale
... df.scale = 3860
... 
... # Process: Buffer
... arcpy.Buffer_analysis("Parcels.lyr", "C:/Tmp/GIS_Tmp/300ft_shp", Distance__Buff1, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "", "PLANAR")
... 
... #Import Symbology layer to buffer
... arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management ("300ft_shp", "C:/Tmp/GIS_Tmp/Symbol_300ft.lyr")
... 
... # Process: Buffer (2)
... arcpy.Buffer_analysis("Parcels.lyr", "C:/Tmp/GIS_Tmp/500ft_shp", Distance__Buff2, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "", "PLANAR")
... 
... #Import Symbology layer to buffer
... arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management ("500ft_shp", "C:/Tmp/GIS_Tmp/Symbol_300ft.lyr")
... 
... # Update Text within Title
... import arcpy
... mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
... for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
...     # Text not within Element
...     if elm.text == "Text":
...         elm.text = "fine"
... arcpy.RefreshTOC()
... del mxd
... 
... #Update Text for Date
... 
... from datetime import date, timedelta   
... mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
... #Where my code says "DateTimeElm" your text element needs to be named the same or change this name to reflect your text element  
... elm = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT", "DateTimeElm")[0]  
... elm.text = date.strftime(date.today() - timedelta(days=1), "Current: " + '%B %d, %Y')  
... arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: Beware: Deleting and reposting can result in termination of your account for abuse.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286263/error-when-converting-script-into-tool
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286228/creating-tool-from-script-using-arcpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Script Tool by right clicking a Tool Box and selecting Add Script. Then configure your parameters on the Parameters tab.

[Script Tool Documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-creating-script-tools.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E830E339F03D4C81AB30DDAFE443F050)